# Accediendo a índices de un *array que no se han creado previamente

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

Ando realizando unas pruebas funcionales en una **máquina de 32bits** en donde un tipo de estructura A (Estante), contempla un segundo tipo de estructura B (Articulo). Esta estructura B (Articulos) **puede incrementar o decrementar su tamaño** en base a ciertas lógicas de negocio del software, por lo que la he declarado como **puntero** y voy incrementando o decrementando su tamaño con **malloc**

**Mi duda recide en la cantidad de elementos que tiene el objeto B dentro de A**, me explico:

```
typedef struct articulo {
   int id;
   char serie[3] = {'S','D', 'A'};
} Articulo;

typedef struct estante {
   Articulo *articulos;
} Estante;

int main(void) {
    Estante myEstante;
    myEstante.articulos = malloc(3*sizeof(articulo));
}
```

En este punto, por lo que entiendo, **he redimensionado el puntero articulos a tamaño 3**, por lo que se supone que existen estante.articulos[0], estante.articulos[1] y estante.articulos[2]. Es más, puedo acceder a sus propiedades:

```
printf("Prop: %c", estante.articulos[1].serie[0]); //Prop: S
```

Si accedo al tamaño del puntero me dice que es de 4bytes, y si obtengo el tamaño de cada índice me indica un total de 7bytes (4 del int y 3 del char). En este sentido no tengo problema alguno y lo entiendo.

```
printf("Tam 1 %d", sizeof(myEstante.articulos[0])); // 7bytes
printf("Tam 2 %d", sizeof(myEstante.articulos[1])); // 7bytes
printf("Tam 3 %d", sizeof(myEstante.articulos[2])); // 7bytes
```

Lo que no entiendo es que, **si yo accedo a un índice del array que yo nunca he creado**, me dice también que es de tamaño 7 ¿Cómo es posible?

```
printf("Tam 100", sizeof(myEstante.articulos[100])); // 7bytes
```

No soy un experto con punteros en C, así que pido disculpas de antemano si he cometido algún error de sintaxis o alguna explicación.

Answer (score 2):

El operador `sizeof` tiene una particularidad interesante que vale la pena señalar: no evalúa las expresiones que se le pasan, sólo calcula el tamaño del resultado. Por lo tanto este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f()
{
    for (unsigned long long i = 0ull; i != ~0ull; ++i)
        printf("%llu\n", i);

    return 42;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    printf("sizeof = %lu\n", sizeof(i = f()));
    return 0;
}
```

Se ejecuta en unas milésimas de segundo y [muestra la siguientes salida](https://tio.run/##PY5BCsIwEEXXmVOMFSGhKkXcxXoSN6VN60CcSNq4UPTqMTXqZvh8@O9Nu2ltw0OMS@LWhs7gYZw6ctvzEYB4wl4qeIDonUcZeKSBTYfW8ZAPYY1VsFantKjxlXNZkgIhrj4RelmsrA0nLtZISgMIb6bgGfc7Dc8suTTE8uao@7jmhjT85yPdjeuTaPXF5ELO7vSeStAfs0rIGN8):

> ```
> sizeof = 4
> ```

Si hubiese evaluado `i = f()` podría haber tardado varios minutos en contar desde cero a el valor máximo de un entero de 64 bits sin signo. ¿Por qué es importante esto?

Porque has pedido calcular el tamaño del centesimoprimer elemento de una formación que tiene tres elementos:

```
myEstante.articulos = malloc(3*sizeof(articulo));
//                           ^ <--- Tres elementos.
printf("Tam 100", sizeof(myEstante.articulos[100])); // 7bytes
//                                           ^^^ <--- Centesimoprimer elemento.
```

Esto no genera ningún error en tiempo de ejecución porque el operador `sizeof` no va a ir a buscar a la formación `articulos` la instancia que ocupa la posición `100` para medir su tamaño ¿Por qué debería hacer eso? ¡Ya sabe que su tamaño será 7, como todas las demás instancias!

Si quieres medir el tamaño de una formación, tendrás que distinguir entre formaciones de tamaño estático y formaciones de tamaño dinámico. De las formaciones de tamaño estático (como `char serie[3]`) se obtiene el tamaño directamente de la formación ya que su tamaño es implícito en el tipo, pero de las formaciones de tamaño dinámico (su memoria se pide con `malloc`) es imposible obtener su tamaño en tiempo de ejecución:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[3];
    int *b = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    printf("sizeof a = %lu\nsizeof b = %lu\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(b));
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##VYxBDsIgEEXXcopJjQk0aky6rHoRdQEUdBIKhoILjWfHaVpN3L3//p/RG@2kv5ayRK9d7gzsh9Rh2N6O7E85VKNj6BP0Ej1/BOwEe7HFaOSpubQT1goOtHAuaD7g0wTLSQuooRE0uUdKlldTBZLGK5fPfs7qm6s1zNdS/FCJ8YWNxhASRZNy9LBr2buUDw):

> ```
> sizeof a = 12
> sizeof b = 8
> ```

El tamaño de `a` es doce porque son tres enteros (de cuatro bytes cada uno), el tamaño de `b` es ocho porque es un puntero a una dirección de 64 bits.

Comment: Entonces me surge una duda. Para controlar el tamaño (indices) de las formaciones de tamaño dinámico ¿Tendría que controlar dicho tamaño en una variable estática independiente e incrementarla o decrementarla su valor según necesite?

Comment: Efectivamente, para saber el tamaño de una formación estática, deberás guardar dicho tamaño en una variable independiente.

Comment: Pues muchísimas gracias por la aclaración, me ha sido de gran ayuda :-D